# D3 scale fails if first value is different than zero

Tags: css, d3.js, linear-gradients, colorbar

In this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/2VeGY/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>single column</title>
<style>
    *{margin:0,padding:0}
    input{width:800px;}
    nav{border:1px solid gray; width:850px;}
    li{display:inline-block; height:30px;  }
    li:hover{opacity:0.8}
</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body>

<input value="[{&quot;v&quot;:0,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;red&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:100,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;#005&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:200,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;#12d&quot;}, {&quot;v&quo\
t;:300,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;#1dd&quot;}, {&quot;v&quot;:400,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;red&quot;} ]">
  <nav>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script>

  var wscale = d3.scale.linear().range(["0px","800px"])

  update()
  d3.select("input").on("change",update)

  function update(){
      var data = JSON.parse(d3.select("input").property("value"));
      var li=d3.select("ul").selectAll("li").data(data);

      wscale.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.v}))

      li.enter().append("li")

      li
        .style("width",function(d,i){
            start=d.v
            i+1 == data.length ? end=d.v : end=data[i+1].v;
            return wscale(end-start)
        })
        .style("background-image",function(d,i){
            start=d.c;
            i+1 == data.length ? end=d.c : end=data[i+1].c;
            return "linear-gradient(to right, "+start+","+end+")"});

      li.exit().remove()

  }

  </script>
```

you can change the color scale of the steps `data[...].c` and their position `data[...].v`.
The scale is updated dynamically.

My problem is the following: Why it messes up if the first value is different than zero?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What first value? How does the scale fail?

Comment: Look in the input field: http://jsfiddle.net/2VeGY/1/ if you change the last `v:400` value into, for example, `v:1000`, the gradients are automatically updated, but if you change the **first** `v:0` value into something different, the widths are not calculated correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behaviour because with your current code, you *always* pass 0 as an input value to `wscale`. For the last `li` element, `end` is going to be the same as `start` in your function to set the `width` and therefore what you're passing to `wscale` will be 0. The input domain of `wscale` is determined as the extent of the input values and doesn't take this additional value into account.

You can easily fix this by changing how the domain is determined:

```
wscale.domain([0, d3.max(data,function(d){return d.v})]);
```

This assumes that all of your `v` values are positive.

However, what you really want to do is take into account the *differences* between the values, as that's what you're passing to the scale. That is, the total sum of differences should be equal to the maximum width. You can compute this as follows.

```
var sumdiff = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    sumdiff += data[i+1].v - data[i].v;
}
```

Then the scale becomes

```
wscale.domain([0, sumdiff]);
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2VeGY/4/).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to explain me the bug. I don't understand why it does not work with negatives. How could I fix it?

Comment: The code above assumes that 0 is the start (i.e. smallest value) of the scale. If you have negative values, you need to put the smallest as the start. Basically, you need to make sure that 0 is in the domain to make it work.

Comment: I am sorry but here http://jsfiddle.net/2VeGY/3 after taking into account your suggestions, the result still have some problem, in particular the **sum** of the width is not anymore 600px as it should be as the range is `[0px,600px]`

Comment: Anddd... http://jsfiddle.net/2VeGY/5/ voilà, thanking your suggestions now the colorbar works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't put the quotation marks in the range, it should be like so:

```
.range([0,800])
```

Comment: What you suggest implies the use of `.attr("width")`, and it does not work, or the use of `.style("width")` adding `+"px"` to the value, and it does not work either

Comment: same result. It fails calculating, the proportions, I think there's a bug in the code that I cannot find

Comment: uhm my bad I think I misunderstood your question, I thought you were asking for a problem on the range